# asp.net menu control adapter disable javascript

Tags: asp.net, control-adapter

Hi im trying to write a control adapter for the menu control.
But how do i stop it from loading a javascript?

it renders the following line `new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'menu1', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'vertical', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });` i can't find a way to stop that..

```
Public Class MenuAdapter
    Inherits WebControlAdapter

    Private ReadOnly Property Menu As Menu
        Get
            Return CType(MyBase.Control, Menu)
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub RenderBeginTag(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Control.ClientID)) Then
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, Control.ClientID)
        End If
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Control.CssClass)) Then
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, Control.CssClass)
        End If
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RenderEndTag(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        writer.WriteLine()
        writer.RenderEndTag()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RenderContents(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        RenderItems(writer, Menu.Items)
    End Sub

    Private Sub RenderItems(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter, menuItems As MenuItemCollection)
        For Each menuItem As MenuItem In Menu.Items
            If (HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(menuItem.NavigateUrl).Equals(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then
                writer.AddAttribute("class", Menu.StaticSelectedStyle.CssClass)
            End If
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Li)
            If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(menuItem.NavigateUrl)) Then
                writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, Menu.ResolveClientUrl(menuItem.NavigateUrl))
                writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A)
                writer.Write(menuItem.Text)
                writer.RenderEndTag()
            Else
                writer.Write(menuItem.Text)
            End If
            If (menuItem.ChildItems.Count > 0) Then
                RenderBeginTag(writer)
                RenderItems(writer, menuItem.ChildItems)
                RenderEndTag(writer)
            End If
            writer.RenderEndTag()
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding OnPreRender and not calling the base method seems to solve the problem.